# Ruby on Rails: String with variable parsing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, date

in ruby i can build a Variable with the date like this

```
irb(main):004:0> a = "#{Date.today}" => "2012-03-23"
```

But how can i do this with a already created string:

```
irb(main):005:0> a = '#{Date.today}' => "\#{Date.today}"
```

The background is, that i'am storing a path with different variables in a database and i need to replace these variables at runtime.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you can't avoid it I guess you can use eval

Answer (score 2):

You could `eval` the string like

```
a = 'Date.today'
result = eval(a)
```

While this works, it's can be extremely dangerous if you don't fully control the contents of that string (which is *really* hard if deal with any kind of user input).

So in general you are advised to never use `eval`. Instead you could build some simple DSL (domain specific language) where you have tokens in your string that are later replaced with pre-calculated values. A simple example could be:

```
a = "Today is :today"
result = a.gsub(/:(\w+)/) do |match|
  case $1
  when "today"
    Date.today.to_s
  end
end
```

As you are not evaluing arbitrary Ruby code, this is much safer. Alternatively, depending on your actual usage, you might also be satisfied with [String formatting](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25).

Comment: i recommend using scan instead of gsub for finding multiple matches

Comment: a = '#{Date.today}'
result = eval(a)
this ones just returns nil.
But i will use your suggestion to build a simple DSL. Thank you.

Comment: @padde: `scan` doesn't help here as it doesn't allow to change matched parts of the source string which in this case is equally important to just finding the matches.

Comment: @HolgerJust: i see, so `gsub` is to `sub` what `scan` is to `match`? with a Java Script background i've been missing the global modifier `/.../g` in Ruby. Seems there are globally matching methods for this, though.

Comment: @padde: `gsub` is an (optionally regex based) search and replace with global modifier. `scan`and `match` are two variants of searches (without the replace). For more details see the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to run arbitrary Ruby code, you can use eval like this:

```
a = '#{Date.today}'
eval("\"#{a}\"")
```